# Does anyone know why this isn't working? Working on: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instea

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace, php-7, preg-replace-callback

When we switched to php7 suddenly a particular Wordpress plugin started to trough this error:

```
preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead.
```

So i've started to search (i'm not a php expert) and came with this rewriting of the call.

Something is definitely wrong (although the error disappeared) because the plugin does not do the job.
Any clue somebody? Thank you

```
//old
//$rewrite_rules = unserialize( preg_replace         ( '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!se',                        "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'"         , $rewrite_rules ) );
//new
  $rewrite_rules = unserialize( preg_replace_callback( '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!s',  function($m) { return ("'s:'.strlen('$m[2]').':\"$m[2]\";'");}, $rewrite_rules ) );
```

Comment: Your still have the code written inside a string literal, see `("'s:'.strlen('$m[2]').':\"$m[2]\";'");`

Comment: Try `preg_replace_callback('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!s',  function($m) { return "'s:'" . strlen($m[2]) . ':"' . $m[2] . '";\'');}, $rewrite_rules )`

Comment: i've tried with small change  because of syntax error -> removed the extra ")", but still doesn't work `preg_replace_callback('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!s',   function($m) { return "'s:'" . strlen($m[2]) . ':"' . $m[2] . '";\'';}, $rewrite_rules )`

Comment: no error thrown, but the plugin doesn't do the job

Comment: Is it inside a class? What is the input like?

Comment: it is inside a function that is inside a class. `function filter_rewrite_rules( $rewrite_rules ) {/* some code*/ $rewrite_rules = unserialize( preg_replace_callback('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!s',   function($m) { return "'s:'" . strlen($m[2]) . ':"' . $m[2] . '";\'';}, $rewrite_rules ) );   }`

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: thank you, now it throws this `preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, 'UtilString::rewrite_callback', to be a valid callback ` that definitely beats me up

Comment: Maybe you should remove the array way of declaring and just pass `'rewrite_callback'` as the callback argument? Please try the one below. It would be much easier if you could provide a minimal complete verifyable example (MCVE).

Comment: Please also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575008/preg-replace-callback-problem

Comment: thank you, i do understand your point (sorry for that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your callback:

```
function($m) { return ("'s:'.strlen('$m[2]').':\"$m[2]\";'");}
```

The biggest one is that it returns the string:

```
"'s:'.strlen('$m[2]').':\"$m[2]\";'"
```

Being a string enclosed in double quotes, the variables are substituted with their values but that's all. Apparently you need to also find the length of `$m[2]` and the function [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) is the right tool for this job. But here `strlen` are just some characters in a string, not a function call. In order properly call `strlen()` to get the length of `$m[2]` it should be invoked as PHP code, outside the string, like this:

```
's:'.strlen($m[2]).':"'.$m[2].'";'
```

Even better, use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to produce the output in a clean way, without worrying about quotes and escaping quotes inside quotes and so on:

```
function (array $m) {
    return sprintf('s:%d:"%s";', strlen($m[2]), $m[2]);
}
```

Comment: well explained! thank you @axiac, that did the job! sorry i can't upvote because of the profile reputation!